# Daisy chain Docker Compose files on Dockerized dependencies

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a web application (Angular) that is backed by a single web service. This web service in turn communicates to several different databases and downstream/subsequent web services. Each of these web services typically has its own database or 3rd party backing web service behind it as well.

For instance:

```
my-web-app -->
  my-main-web-service -->
    psql-db
    billing-web-service -->
      stripe
      redis-db
    fulfillment-web-service -->
      3rd-party-logistics-service
    user-service -->
      mongo-db
```

- the web app talks only to its own "main" web service
- this "main" web service talks to its own PSQL and my Billing, Fulfillment and User Services
- my Billing Service talks to Stripe and its own Redis DB
- my Fulfillment Service talks to a 3rd party fulfillment/logistics partner
- my User Service talks to its own MongoDB

All of these apps, services and DBs are containerized (Docker), and the app and all four services exist inside their own independent project/repo.

Locally, I have a `docker-compose.yml` file that runs everything described above as a suite of Docker containers.

However, I would also like to be able to just run one of the services as a standalone container (plus whatever its backing resources/databases are) at a time.

Ideally, there would be a way to somehow "*daisy chain*" Docker Compose files together such that:

- the Docker Compose file for Billing Web Service defines a container for itself and for its Redis DB
- the Docker Compose file for Fulfillment Service defines a container for itself
- the Docker Compose file for User Service defines a container for itself and its Mongo DB
- the Docker Compose file for the Main Web Service defines a container for itself, its PSQL DB **and somehow invokes the Docker Compose files for the above three (3) services as well**
- the Docker Compose file for the Web App defines a container for itself and **somehow invokes the Docker Compose file for the Main Web Service**

Being able to do this, I wouldn't have duplicate container ("services") configurations across all these Docker Compose files, and I could run whatever Docker Compose I want and it will trigger all the correct services being spun up.

If I just want to run Billing Service and its Redis DB, I would just run `docker-compose [OPTIONS] up` from inside the Billing Service, and only those two components would run.

But if I wanted to run the Main Web Service locally, running `docker-compose [OPTIONS] up` on its Docker Compose file would first (in a recursive manner) run the Docker Compose for Billing, Fulfillment and User Services, then start its own PSQL container and finally the Main Web Service container (once all its backing services are up and running).

Ditto for the Web App.

**Can either Docker or Docker Compose do this?** The idea is to let each component (app, service, etc.) define its own set of Docker Compose services (containers), but to organize the dependencies such that if one component/project/repo requires another, it will almost "import" its Docker Compose config into its own and run it first.

Comment: What you are describing sounds like the sort of thing Kubernetes is for. You would have a bunch of deployments for each self-contained app (web service + redis DB, user service + mongo db, etc) and the apps in them talk to each other. Perhaps you should look into Kubernetes.

Answer (score 0):

Your mileage may vary on this for what you specifically have in mind, but you can specify multiple compose files when invoking `docker-compose`, e.g.

`docker-compose -f dc-base.yml -f dc-service1.yml -f dc-service2.yml`

So I'm guessing you'd need to do the correct chaining yourself when running docker compose, but you can split this into logical units using separate files.

See [docker compose docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/#use--f-to-specify-name-and-path-of-one-or-more-compose-files)